# Delete original matching file on rename truncation

Tags: file, windows-7, filenames, delete-file, truncate

A friend of mine was hit with the Krypto virus.  Thankfully they had Carbonite installed. So, they went ahead and restored only the affected files (.xls, .doc, jpg, scans, etc.. there were a bunch). Unfortunately they did not restore everything which would have simplified this considerably.

A restore from carbonite has been done to the directories.. now we have files that are the right ones (they all have the string: (Restored) starting at the 28th character from the end. Plus we have other valid files that krypto DID NOT encrypt.

Unfortunately, whomever did the carbonite restore put only selected files (xls, doc, ppt, etc) and left the others as is. So I can't just delete all the files. When I truncate the name... the other file exists. (THEY are frozen by the Krypto virus)... so I just want them gone. But I have to leave the other files that were not affected in place.

So lets assume I have the following files in a directory

```
afile1 (Restored) 11-23-2010 14.07.DOC (this filename would be truncated at 
                                       the " ("   since there is already a file 
                                       called afile1.doc in the directory. 
afile1.doc                             (This file needs to be DELETED BEFORE the truncation
                                       the above filename so no conflict with duplicate FN 

break.txt                              (This file has no matching file 
                                       with Restored in the name, leave alone)
cat.zip                                (This file has no matching file 
                                       with Restored in the name, leave alone)
fred (Restored) 01-14-14 13.28.JPG     (This filename would be truncated at the " (" 
                                       but first, again the file below would have to be deleted
fred.jpg                               (This file needs to be deleted before the truncation 
                                       of the above filename so it won't create duplicate file
```

So far, I am trying to figure out... (or anything else I might have missed!)

How can I

1. test for existence of a matching file name where up to the " (Restored)" there is already an existing file with that name (as shown in the example above (afile1.doc & fred.jpg)
2. delete the already existing file (OR at least "prepend deleteme to a flie which we will have to manually delete???  then
3. Then truncate the last 28 characters of the filename with (Restored) in it so it is properly named and in the right place, thus preventing a duplicate file situation or worse, adding characters to the end of the valid file

I have to do this for all files under a directory too. (There are countless directories where files are stored).

I need to be left with the following files:

```
afile1.doc  (this was the file that had (Restored) in the name and was truncated)
break.txt
cat.zip
fred.jpg    (this was another file that had (Restored) in the name and was truncated)
```

I hope that makes sense.